# CL/Scheme DSELs with non-lisp syntax

Tags: scheme, common-lisp, dsl

I have been curious lately about DSLs, specifically, how to implement them in Lisp,
since it looks like a piece of cake compare to the alternatives.

Looking for information I cannot find any evidence of a non-lisp DSEL in Lisp in internet.

So my question is:

- Is it possible to implement a DSL with non-lisp syntax in lisp with the use of macros?
- How is this achieved?
- Can the reader of lisp be replaced by a custom reader that translates code to lisp structure?

  - If the former is true: is this a common way to implement "non-lispy" DSELs?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid Lisp syntax? It is very easy to use, and adapting e.g. the `emacs` lisp mode for your DSL would then be very easy. If you have your own syntax, you'll also need in practice an indenter, a pretty printer, some editor style (to at least highlight and autoindent properly), etc...

Comment: This is really too broad, but the simple answer is "yes".  I believe there's a C-syntax readtable floating around somewhere.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Parcil http://www.flownet.com/ron/lisp/parcil.lisp

Comment: It's exceptionally trivial to add syntax front-ends to Lisp. See CL-PEG, or dozens of other parsing libraries. Take a look at https://github.com/combinatorylogic/mbase for example.

Answer (score 8):

Short version: [Racket](http://www.racket-lang.org) does this.

In more detail: Racket, a descendant of Scheme, has a really well-thought-out story here. A Racket module/file can begin with a language declaration, e.g.

`#lang algol60`

... and then the rest of the file can be written in the given language. (Yes, [algol60 is built in](https://github.com/plt/racket/tree/master/pkgs/algol60).)

In order to develop your own language, you need to write a package that is a language specification, that shows how to expand the syntax of this language into the syntax of the underlying language (in this case, Racket). Anyone can write such packages, and then distribute them to allow others to write programs in this language. There are examples of such language specifications included with Racket, e.g. the algol 60 example mentioned earlier.

I think this is exactly what you're asking for?

ObDisclaimer: Yes, I am a Racket developer.

Comment: Well, very informative. Actually I am more taking a look in general. My choice will be a small lisp/scheme such as s7 or so, because I am targetting games and mobile devices.

Comment: Does that mean it's possible for Racket to write language specifications for every other language. Like perhaps writing PHP/Javascript syntax that gets interpreted into Racket?

Comment: (I guess I should add that it might not constitute a *specification*--what you're describing would be an implementation, pure and simple.)

Answer (score 7):

How do you implement the surface language of a programming language? You write a parser or use a parser generator. You can do that in Lisp, too.

There are many examples of general purpose and domain specific languages written in Lisp - not using s-expression syntax.

Historically the first [ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)) (an extension language for a theorem prover) was written in Lisp. [Macsyma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macsyma) (a language for computer algebra) is written in Lisp. In many cases there is some kind of 'end user', for which a non-s-expression language needs to be written/supported. Sometimes there are languages which exist and need to be supported.

Using macros and read macros you can implement some languages or extend the Lisp language. For example it is easy to add JSON syntax to Lisp using a read macro. Also some kind of [infix syntax](http://www.cliki.net/infix). XML (example: [XMLisp](http://agentsheets.com/lisp/XMLisp/)).

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem in supporing non-Lisp syntax DSLs in Lisp. You'll need to use some parser/parser generator library as Rainer has mentioned. A good example is [esrap](http://nikodemus.github.io/esrap/) that is used to parse markdown (see [3bmd](https://github.com/3b/3bmd)) and also for the [pgloader command language](http://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/10/01-loading-geolocation-data) which is just an example of an external DSL you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

From *Let Over Lambda*, there is an implementation of Perl style regular expressions: http://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap4.html#sec_4.

Also there are several attempts at making a "non-lispy" version of Lisp, the main one being the Readable Lisp S-expression Project: http://readable.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 0):

One implementation-specific solution that sticks out (if you want to use Scheme rather than CL) is [Gambit Scheme's](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) built-in support for infix syntax via its [SIX-script](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/doc/gambit-c.html#Scheme-infix-syntax-extension) extension.

This provides a rich set of loosely C-like operators and syntax forms, which can either be used out-of-the-box to write code in a C-like style, or redefined to mean whatever you want (you can easily redefine e.g. the function definition format, if you aren't a fan of `type name(args) {}`). `for`, `case`, `:=` and so on (even `goto`) are all already present and ready to mean whatever you need.

The actual core of the syntax (operator precedence, expressions vs. statements) is fixed, but you can assign things like a Scheme binding construct to the s-expression produced by an operator for a reasonably large amount of freedom.

```
a = b * c;
```

is translated by the reader into

```
(six.x=y (six.identifier a) (six.x*y (six.identifier b) (six.identifier c)))
```

You can then override the definitions of those macros with your own to make the syntax do whatever you want. Turning the C-style base into a Haskell-looking functional language isn't too hard (strategically redefine `=` and `->` and you're halfway there...).